# Formatting JSON Data with ColdFusion for HighCharts

Tags: json, coldfusion, highcharts

So I'm working on a pie chart using HighSlide and ColdFusion.

To make this simple, for the data it expects a string like this:

```
data: [{name: 'Jane',y: 13}, {name: 'John',y: 23}, {name: 'Joe',y: 19}]
```

What i've done to accomplish this is to loop through my query results and create a string like this:

```
<cfloop query="getAreaCounts">
     <cfset areaList = listAppend(areaList, "{name: '#name#',y: #y#}")>
</cfloop>
```

I know there has to be an easier/smarter way right?  Since this is JSON data, i figured I could just do this:

```
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(getAreaCounts)#</cfoutput>
```

But that returns a JSON string like this which highcharts won't process:

```
{"COLUMNS":["Y","NAME"],"DATA":[[8,"Area1"],[7,"Area2"],[1,"Area3"],[1,"Area4"]]}
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great.  Do I need to dig deeper into a JSON - howto?

Comment: FYI - Sean's comment includes the process of looping through the query and is more complete than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to convert the query to an array of structs and then run `serializeJSON()` on that array.

Below is a method that I use pretty frequently when working with a lot of queries and JSON. I think that I got it from Ben Nadel's site and then converted it to cfscript.. I'll try to track down the blog post after I post this answer.

```
public array function queryToArray( required query qry ) {
    var columns = arguments.qry.getColumnNames();
    var ofTheJedi = [];

    for( var i = 1; i LTE qry.recordCount; i++ ) {
        var obj = {};

        for( var k = 1; k LTE arrayLen( columns ); k++ ) {
            structInsert( obj, columns[ k ], arguments.qry[ columns[ k ] ][ i ] );
        }

        arrayAppend( ofTheJedi, obj );
    }

    return ofTheJedi;
}
```

So, in your case you would do something like this:

```
<cfset myJSON = queryToArray( getAreaCounts ) />
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON( myJSON )#</cfoutput>
```

EDIT: Here's Ben's blog post that inspired the method above: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/124-Ask-Ben-Converting-a-Query-to-an-Array.htm

Comment: I've seen that method before from Ben but it didn't come to mind when fixing my issue, thanks for that Sean.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (untested but you get the idea)

```
<cfscript>
data = [{name='Jane',y=13],{name='John',y=23},{name='Joe',y=19}];
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>#serializeJson(data)#</cfoutput>
```

You need to create a Coldfusion array of strucutres (each with "name" and "y" as members).. *then* serialize it. What you are serializeing above is the query object. By your code it looks like you *meant* to serialze the "arealist" variable - but that var would probably not come out correct either because it is not an array of structures - it is a list of strings.

Comment: While it doesn't address using a query, I'm just doing some proof of concept stuff and the array of structures is what i was missing, thanks Mark!

Comment: if `name` and `y` need to be lowercase, simply wrap in quotes, otherwise they will be uppercased in serialiseJSON()